# How to use findOrCreate in Sequelize

Tags: database, oauth, sequelize.js

I am a Sequelize beginner.
I'd like to oAuth authenticate with Twitter or Facebook and want to save user information in the database.

But if OAuth authentication is done on multiple sites, there is a problem that information such as `userid` registered in the database will collide with the other sites.

In order to avoid this, I would like to do a process to update the database only when the specified `userid` does not already exist in the database.

I knew that we could use Sequelize's `findOrCreate` to do it, but I do not know how to use `findOrCreate`.
I know how to use upsert and I'd like to use `findOrCreate` like the description of upsert below. However, we want to perform conditional branching like this:

`if (userid! = "○○○" && username! = "○○○")`.

```js
User.upsert({
  userid:    profile.id,
  username:  profile.username,
  accountid: c + 1,
}).then(() => {
  done(null, profile);
});
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```js
// remember to use a transaction as you are not sure whether the user is
// already present in DB or not (and you might end up creating the user -
// a write operation on DB)

models.sequelize.transaction(function(t) {
  return models.users.findOrCreate({
    where: {
      userId:    profile.userId,
      name:      profile.name
    },
    transaction: t
  })
  .spread(function(userResult, created){
    // userResult is the user instance

    if (created) {
      // created will be true if a new user was created
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Worth noting that Sequelize will automatically create the transaction if one is not provided in the options to [findOrCreate](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findOrCreate)

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use Sequelize hooks. You'd want to make your hook callback async (Sequelize supports it), so in the hook you can run your check and return a promise only if your check is successful (and throw an error otherwise).

Answer (score 2):

In **findOrCreate()** method **defaults:** option is significant and valuable.

You can use some values for **where:** condition and add the remaining in **defaults:** option.

```
User.findOrCreate({
   where: {userId: profile.id},
   defaults: {
        name: profile.name,
        address: profile.address,
   }
}).then((userRow, isCreated) => {
if(isCreated){
       //user created
       console.log('creted user', userRow);
   }
});
```

In the above example, we're not adding **name** and **address** values in the where: condition because I believe name and address can be the same and these are also not unique in the table.

Comment: For more detail official documentation for stable version of V6.0 [official findOrCreate](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-finders/#findorcreate)