# How to use sequelize findorcreate in bulk import?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use the `findOrCreate` function in a CSV import to prevent multiple users being created with the same email address but it isn't working.

I import all the rows in a CSV file into memory:

```
importableCsvRows.forEach(row => importData(row))
```

Then I iterate over each row to import a user:

```
function importData (row) {
  const name = row[0]
  const email = row[1]
  addUser(name, email)
}
```

In the addUser function I use findOrCreate:

```
function addUser (name, email) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const user = models.users.findOrCreate({
      where: {email: email},
      defaults: { email: email, name: name }
    })
    .then(u => {
      return resolve(u)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('ERROR', err)
      return reject(err)
    })
  })
}
```

The problem is that multiple transactions get started because findOrCreate is async so before the first row finishes processing, the next row starts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43403084/how-to-use-findorcreate-in-sequelize

Comment: nope I've tried that, still opens up 5 transactions at once

Comment: The simplest way is to use the `for` loop

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `forEach` you need to wait until the db transaction finishes before you start importing the next user.

Simplest way would be to [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) the `importData`function:

```
async function importData (row) {
  const name = row[0]
  const email = row[1]
  try {
    await addUser(name, email)
  } catch(err) {
    //console.log?
  }
}
```

Also, in `addUser`: There is no need to return your own Promise. Just return the promise `findOrCreate` returns:

```
function addUser (name, email) {
    return models.users.findOrCreate({
      where: {email: email},
      defaults: { email: email, name: name }
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, `forEach` doesn't wait for promises between iterations

Comment: @mu3 the version @simon.ro wrote does work, and indeed `forEach` doesn't wait for promises, but you'd be using the wrong tool for the job it you want to `forEach` and await for promises. Instead, one can use foreach or other loop construct that awaits for promises. I know this is a very old thread but adding this for others that might come across it.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no native bulk alternative to `findOrCreate`, we have to do it manually (as you have already tried).

`Promise.all` + `map` can be helpful here. [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) runs all requests in parallel and act as a [Barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_(computer_science)) that will wait until all promises are fulfilled.

Here is a simple working code sample:

```js
async function addUserRows(userRow) {
  return await Promise.all(
    rows.map(addUserRow)
  );
}
```

```js
async function addUserRow(row) {
  const [name, email] = row;
  return addUser(name, email)
}
```

```js
async function addUser (name, email) {
  return models.users.findOrCreate({
    where: {email},
    defaults: { email, name }
  });
}
```

## What if I have *a lot* of rows?

If you use Bluebird's [Promise.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) instead, things get a bit simpler, and you can even constrain the max concurrent amount of in-flight promises, which is absolutely desirable, if you have a lot of rows.

However, an even more advanced approach would be to use two sequential queries:

1. First query gets all missing entries.
2. Second query writes all missing entries (using [bulkCreate](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-bulkCreate))
3. If you have *way too many rows*, slice the big set into smaller batches and repeat until all batches are sent out.